# multiple tap and pay apps - is it possible?

Tags: google-pay, google-wallet

I use google wallet for paying with my phone in stores. Recently I downloaded a new app (via my credit card provider- I gain credits that I can use as money) and I would like to use it as a **secondary** payment app.

My issue is that this new app won't allow me to use it unless I make it my default payment app. I wanted to know if this is a general requirement or something I should contact the support to fix.

I want to continue to use google as my default payment app, unless I specifically want to use the new app. Is that at all possible?

Comment: That is how it should work... Typically Google Pay would be your primary app, any other app you would have to manually open, then you could use it for Tap to Pay.